# Hide download and print option in pdf(mpdf or fpdi) in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf, fpdi

I don't want to show download and print option in pdf, Is there any way to hide the navbar or toolbar in pdf using pdf libraries(mpdf or fpdi) in codeigniter?

Comment: what download and print options, exactly? do you mean the features of the browser showing the pdf? if so: no, and it's better that a document can *not* change the behaviour of the displaying program.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. And Is there any other way to merge multiple pdf, that can only to be viewed? and that should be in pdf format.